# Recycle View dont collapse toolbar in fragment! why?

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

i use [this tutorial](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=404735061d-Android_Weekly_159&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-404735061d-337898309) for making collapsing toolbar with nestedscrollview. but when i use recycleview in fragment for making tab's the toolbar not react with recycleview  scrolling... how to fix that?

here my code:

layout_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.inthecheesefactory.lab.designlibrary.activity.MainActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_toolbar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/secondColor"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/error_color" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_ok"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemIconTint="#333"
    app:itemTextColor="#333"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />
```

tabview and viewpager handle in MainActivity:

```
  final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB3"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB4"));


    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

ContactAdapter.java

```
package tab;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;



public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

private List<ContactInfo> contactList;

public ContactAdapter(List<ContactInfo> contactList) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
    ContactInfo ci = contactList.get(i);
    contactViewHolder.vName.setText(ci.name);
    contactViewHolder.vSurname.setText(ci.surname);
    contactViewHolder.vEmail.setText(ci.email);
    contactViewHolder.vTitle.setText(ci.name + " " + ci.surname);
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.carditem, viewGroup, false);

    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView vName;
    protected TextView vSurname;
    protected TextView vEmail;
    protected TextView vTitle;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        vName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        vSurname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);
        vEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}
}
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
package tab;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
            return tab3;
        case 3:
            TabFragment4 tab4 = new TabFragment4();
            return tab4;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

tab_fragment_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cardList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

tab_fragment_1.java

```
package tab;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView v =(RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    SetupRecycleView(v);
    return v;
}

void SetupRecycleView(RecyclerView recList) {
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(G.context);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    // recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
    List<ContactInfo> contactInfos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
        contactInfo.email = "salam " + i;
        contactInfo.name = "salam " + i;
        contactInfo.surname = "salam " + i;
        contactInfos.add(contactInfo);
    }
    ContactAdapter adapter = new ContactAdapter(contactInfos);
    recList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

carditem.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/mainColor"
        android:text="contact det"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSurname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Surname"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtName"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/txtName"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: App Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to build.gradle and make sure you're using com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:**22.2.0**. 
It doesn't work on earlier versions.